# Read several ValidationMessages.properties from classpath

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, properties-file

I have a problem with JSR303 and in special Hibernate-Validator.

I want to read a validation message from a property file. This property file lives in the war file that is deployed to the servlet container. The problem is, it's not accessed. I have the following project structure.

- project-web (war file)

  - project-web-core (jar file in WEB-INF/lib of the project-web.war)

    - hibernate-validator jars (maven dependency of project-web-core)
    - ValidationMessages.properties (in src/main/resources of project-web-core.jar; this one is accessed)
  - ValidationMessages.properties (in src/main/resources of project-web.war; this one **isn't** accessed)

How can I access both ValidationMessages.properties? Or is this impossible?

Beyond that it would be perfect if the Hibernate-Validator first would read the property file in the war and if it wouldn't find the key, then read the property file from the jar and so on.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to have more than one `ValidationMessages.properties` file. But you could use Hibernate Validators [AggregateResourceBundleLocator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/resourceloading/AggregateResourceBundleLocator.html) to retrieve messages from bundles with different names like this:

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = configuration
    .messageInterpolator(
        new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
            new AggregateResourceBundleLocator(
                Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), 
                configuration.getDefaultResourceBundleLocator())))
    .buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
```

Comment: Hi Gunnar, thanks for your answer, but i still have a understanding problem. i want use the hibernate annotations for the validation. how is this possible with the above mentoined validationFactory

Comment: Basically you retrieve a `javax.validator.Validator` from the factory, which offers several methods for validating objects. You may have a look into the Hibernate Validator reference guide (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-gettingstarted.html) for getting started with Bean Validation.

Comment: It should be noted that @Gunnar wrote the AggregateResourceBundleLocator, so I consider this an authoritative answer :)